# React Native: Touchable Opacity element is clickable on iOS but not Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native app with a typeahead component. The typeahead displays options that overlay other content on the route (see right image below). When a user clicks one of those options, an onPress listener runs a function:

[image]

This all works just fine on iOS. On Android though, the onPress event is never received. Even more strangely, when I try to click on an option lower in the list (like Boston, MA, USA), the onPress event *is* received by the card below the pressed option (Djerba).

Does anyone know what might cause this behavior? I'd be super grateful for any insights others can offer on this query.

Here's the code for the Explore view and the typeahead components.

**Explore.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { gradients, sizing } from '../../style'
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'
import { MountainHero } from '../Heros'
import { CardRow } from '../Card'
import Loading from '../Loading'
import { setExploreSearch, onExploreTypeaheadClick } from '../../actions/locations'
import { Typeahead } from '../Typeahead'

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  scrollView: {
    paddingBottom: sizing.margin,
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 100,
    elevation: 100,
    top: 53,
    width: '100%',
  },
  typeahead: {
    margin: sizing.margin,
    marginBottom: 0,
    width: sizing.screen.width - (2*sizing.margin),
    zIndex: 100,
    elevation: 100,
  }
}

const Explore = props => {
  const { authenticated: a, spotlight, loading } = props;
  let r = (a.recommendedLocations || []);
  if (!r || !spotlight) return null;
  // remove spotlight locations from the recommended locations
  const ids = spotlight.map(i => i.guid);
  const recommended = r.filter(i => ids.indexOf(i.guid) == -1);
  return (
    <LinearGradient style={styles.container} colors={gradients.teal}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
        {loading && (
          <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
            <Loading />
          </View>
        )}
        <MountainHero text='Explore' />
        <Typeahead
          style={styles.typeahead}
          placeholder='Search Cities'
          value={props.exploreSearch}
          onChange={props.setExploreSearch}
          vals={props.exploreTypeahead}
          valKey={'place_id'}
          onTypeaheadClick={props.onExploreTypeaheadClick}
        />
        <CardRow
          text='Explore Places'
          cards={recommended}
          type='location' />
        <CardRow
          text='In the Spotlight'
          cards={spotlight}
          type='location' />
      </ScrollView>
    </LinearGradient>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.users.authenticated,
  spotlight: state.locations.spotlight,
  exploreSearch: state.locations.exploreSearch,
  exploreTypeahead: state.locations.exploreTypeahead,
  loading: state.locations.loading,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setExploreSearch: s => dispatch(setExploreSearch(s)),
  onExploreTypeaheadClick: val => dispatch(onExploreTypeaheadClick(val)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Explore)
```

**Typeahead.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { sizing, GradientInput } from '../style'

const styles = {
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 100,
    elevation: 100,
    height: 400,
    width: '100%',
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
  typeaheadContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 100,
    elevation: 100,
    top: 55,
    width: '100%',
  },
  typeaheadRow: {
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 12,
    paddingBottom: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#eeeeee',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    marginBottom: -1,
  },
  typeaheadRowText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'open-sans',
    lineHeight: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
}

export const Typeahead = props => {
  return (
    <View style={[props.container, props.style]}>
      <GradientInput style={styles.input}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange} />
      <TypeaheadList vals={props.vals}
        valKey={props.valKey}
        onTypeaheadClick={props.onTypeaheadClick} />
    </View>
  )
}

export const TypeaheadList = props => {
  if (!props.vals) return null;
  return (
    <View style={styles.typeaheadContainer}>
      {props.vals.map(i => {
        let text = i.text;
        if (text.length > 31) text = text.substring(0,31) + '...';
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} key={i[props.valKey]}
            style={styles.typeaheadRow}
            onPress={() => props.onTypeaheadClick(i[props.valKey])}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.typeaheadRowText}>{text}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}

export default Typeahead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move Typeahead component below all CardRow components and set position:absolute for Typeahead. Probably on android - the latest view shadow all views before (I am not sure, but I think you have to try it for next discovering issue).

You should also remove `position: absolute` from all but one component. Working code:

**Explore.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { gradients, sizing } from '../../style'
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'
import { MountainHero } from '../Heros'
import { CardRow } from '../Card'
import Loading from '../Loading'
import { setExploreSearch, onExploreTypeaheadClick } from '../../actions/locations'
import { Typeahead } from '../Typeahead'
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  scrollView: {
    paddingBottom: sizing.margin,
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 1,
    elevation: 1,
    top: 53,
    width: '100%',
  },
  topCardRow: {
    paddingTop: sizing.margin + sizing.gradientInput.height,
  },
  typeahead: {
    margin: sizing.margin,
    marginBottom: 0,
    width: sizing.screen.width - (2*sizing.margin),
    zIndex: 1,
    elevation: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: sizing.mountainHero.height,
    left: 0,
  }
}
const Explore = props => {
  const { authenticated: a, spotlight, loading } = props;
  let r = (a.recommendedLocations || []);
  if (!r || !spotlight) return null;
  // remove spotlight locations from the recommended locations
  const ids = spotlight.map(i => i.guid);
  const recommended = r.filter(i => ids.indexOf(i.guid) == -1);
  return (
    <LinearGradient style={styles.container} colors={gradients.teal}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
        {loading && (
          <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
            <Loading />
          </View>
        )}
        <MountainHero text='Explore' />
        <CardRow
          style={styles.topCardRow}
          text='Explore Places'
          cards={recommended}
          type='location' />
        <CardRow
          text='In the Spotlight'
          cards={spotlight}
          type='location' />
        <Typeahead
          style={styles.typeahead}
          placeholder='Search Cities'
          value={props.exploreSearch}
          onChange={props.setExploreSearch}
          vals={props.exploreTypeahead}
          valKey={'place_id'}
          onTypeaheadClick={props.onExploreTypeaheadClick}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </LinearGradient>
  )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.users.authenticated,
  spotlight: state.locations.spotlight,
  exploreSearch: state.locations.exploreSearch,
  exploreTypeahead: state.locations.exploreTypeahead,
  loading: state.locations.loading,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setExploreSearch: s => dispatch(setExploreSearch(s)),
  onExploreTypeaheadClick: val => dispatch(onExploreTypeaheadClick(val)),
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Explore)
```

**Typeahead.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { sizing, GradientInput } from '../style'

const styles = {
  container: {
    zIndex: 1,
    elevation: 1,
    height: 400,
    width: '100%',
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
  typeaheadContainer: {
    zIndex: 1,
    elevation: 1,
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
  },
  typeaheadRow: {
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 12,
    paddingBottom: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#eeeeee',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    marginBottom: -1,
    zIndex: 1,
    elevation: 1,
  },
  typeaheadRowText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'open-sans',
    lineHeight: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
}

export const Typeahead = props => {
  return (
    <View style={[props.container, props.style]}>
      <GradientInput style={styles.input}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange} />
      <TypeaheadList vals={props.vals}
        valKey={props.valKey}
        onTypeaheadClick={props.onTypeaheadClick} />
    </View>
  )
}

export const TypeaheadList = props => {
  if (!props.vals) return null;
  return (
    <View style={styles.typeaheadContainer}>
      {props.vals.map(i => {
        let text = i.text;
        if (text.length > 31) text = text.substring(0,31) + '...';
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} key={i[props.valKey]}
            style={styles.typeaheadRow}
            onPress={() => props.onTypeaheadClick(i[props.valKey])}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.typeaheadRowText}>{text}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}

export default Typeahead
```

Comment: Thanks Arseniy, though I'm not sure how I can do this _and_ keep the typeahead positioned above my content. Would I just absolutely position it on the route and give the top card row a huge paddingTop or something? That seems super hackish :/

Comment: My suggestion:
1) move MountainHero and Typeahead outside ScrollView
2) now you  will know top position for Typeahead
<MountainHero>
<ScrollView>....</..>
<Typeahead>

I know it will change the behavior of the list scroll, but it would help...

Comment: Hmm, well I moved the Typeahead below the CardRows but the click still wasn't triggered. There must be a way to keep the Typeahead inside the ScrollView, right?

Comment: Firstly, importantly find the variant when onClick will work. Try to remove or hide all except Typeahead. In this case, it will work well, if not - try to find the problem in Typeahead

Comment: Many thanks! The notion of moving the Typeahead below the card lists, combined with the notion of removing all `position: absolute` except one, worked!